# Is momentum an assigned property or an observed property?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, measurements

I have been stuck upon this. 
I observe an object which has mass, length, etc. But I cannot observe momentum in it. I define a quantity attached to that object which is equal to product of mass and velocity and termed as momentum. Is speed same as this as well? Am I thinking on correct lines?

Comment: I think you should try to describe in more detail the difference between "observing" a property and "assigning" one. In one sense, even length would be an assigned property that is the difference between the positions of the ends of an object.

Comment: But i can percieve it exists and clearly see it.I can see force as well.But what does momentum conveys

Answer (score 2):

When we say that something is observable, it doesn't mean it is immediate.

Even mass is not immediate, we can not know the mass of an object only by look at it or touch it.

Linear momentum and angular momentum need some operations to determine its value, but the same happens with position through latitude, longitude and altitude.

Answer (score 1):

Even to define position, we must describe a relationship with other matter. You cannot say where something is unless you say where it is relative to something else. Since velocity is a rate of change of position, velocity is also relative, and since momentum depends (classically) on velocity the same is true for momentum.

To define quantities in physics we must first define a reference frame, that is we define the physical matter relative to which we will perform our measurements. We then use that reference matter to set up a coordinate system according to well defined procedures.

This was the insight which led Einstein to relativity, but it is also fundamental to the von Neumann interpretation of quantum mechanics, in which it is seen that Hilbert space has the mathematical structure of a language (quantum logic) to describe the possibilities for measurment results.

Comment: I just want to know simply that is momentum an attribute or a property.We assign it or this physical quantity exists.And if it exists,how we observe it

Comment: I feel I have answered. It is a relationship between an object and the reference frame chosen by an observer.

Comment: Mass we can clearly see it exists as a property.And then we define a reference frame and a standard to measure it.So can we observe momentum and then define it or is it simply a quantity defined by us which helps us to solve problems.Please reply,I am student still learning

Comment: No one helps a student here.And everyone try to show their dominance.You have replied.Thanks for it

Comment: do you think, you "observe" a property, if the object hits you head? How much you are hurt depends on the mass  and the velocity of the object. Maybe the first time you consider it could be the energy, so m*v^2 but with more experiments (maybe not all with your head) you will find out that the property m*v matters as much as the energy .

Answer (score 1):

Observing your definitions, I would say that momentum is an observed property. The entire concept of collision of particles is built upon analysis of momentum. So, it is not something (like Energy) whose physical meaning is not not well understood.

We can obviously observe momentum. Nature has a lot of her workings centred around the concepts of momentum-velocity is often not that important. So, if we can say, momentum is more observed than velocity in nature.

Comment: Can u explain how it is observed property

Comment: Depends on who is observing- see, during a collision, the momentum of a particle is more important to the other particle than its velocity- so the other particle is observing the momentum of the first particle

Comment: Also, the same object cares a lot about its momentum. Even a principle called Heisenberg's uncertainty principle states that we cannot measure the momentum and position simultaneously and accurately.

Comment: So why we define it as p=m*v

Comment: Why it is unlike mass,force?We know its physical nature and reality and then define it as F=m*a

Comment: Because it is easy that way to measure it- and mv is not the only deinition of momentum. Momentum of a wave (which has no mass) is given by $h/\lambda$

Comment: But I cannot percieve th mass times velocity in the object

Comment: Can u suggest a book or link where i can learn all this stuff

Comment: You think you cannot directly perceive it. But you can. That is why we move when we are hit by a large person moving slow, but not when a small object hits you at a faster speed( like a ball of paper).

Comment: Since the larger person has a greater momentum, we perceive his greater momentum by analysing how fast we are moving the man collided with us.

Comment: Are their some physical quantities which cannot be percieved and exists

Comment: perception is a strange thing. For instance, no one has been able to perceive Energy, but we have the entire quantum physics, and classical physics, built on it

Comment: So finally,does momentum is defined by this formula(p=m*v) or its value is calculated by this.

Comment: Calculated by this- I'd like to say, as there are other ways to calculate it too

Comment: And are ther any quantities which are defined by this such as work,inertia,torque

Comment: Mainly for historical reasons, p=mv. Had history taken a different turn, we would have momentum given by  h/λ